# Color not showing in output text when sent via email

Tags: linux, bash, unix, csh, mailx

I have a test script where I am trying to redirect the result in colored text. I have achieved this using linux color codes. It works when I execute the script from command line but when I try to send the output of the script as attachment via mailx it is not showing me the color instead the attachment is appearing with color code# along with the text.

Can anyone help and suggest on this please?

Eg:
In mail attachment,  I'm getting the result as below but in server if the script is executed, the below line is printed (echo'd) in the command prompt properly in RED color.

```
[1;31m This is red text  [0m
```

Code Snippet:

```
#FONT Color
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m'

echo -e "${RED}This is RED Text${NC}" > /tmp/test.txt

echo "Colored text check" | mailx -s "color_test" -a /tmp/test.txt abc@xyz.com
```

Comment: `in coloreHi, I h I have acheieved` - please fix spelling errors and use proper interpunction. `In mail I'm getting` - "mail" is the name for the whole "(electronic) mail system", a system can't "get you the result". A "mail client" (a program) can show the content of a "mail message". What exactly is "getting the result" you presented? `in server the below line is printed` -  what is "printing" the below line? How do you do it?

Comment: Hi Kamil, details are added now.

Comment: The color tags that you use is something that is recognized only by terminals. email programs only know ascii and some know how to interpret html. Color in email is only visible when it is implemented as html. The terminal color codes are only interpreted as ascii text for your email program. They are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
<!--
    Purple: #a20067
    Dark Blue: #005eb8
-->
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
        </head>
        <body>
                <style>
                        p { margin:0; padding:0; }
                        .h { border-width:1px;border-style:solid;background-color:#005eb8;color:#ffffff;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;padding:8px; }
                        .v { border-width:1px;border-style:solid;background-color:#c6c7c8;color:black;font-weight:bold;text-align:left;padding:8px; }
                </style>
```

There you can have an example of a e-mail sent from a terminal with colour, there I just used dark blue, even though I specified purple. It was used later in that e-mail.